# TeamCity 2017, VSTest: realtime logging when tests run using orderedtest file

Tags: teamcity, vstest

If I run tests (selenium webDriver) on TeamCity 2017 (VSTest) separately (f.e. using command "/Tests:Test1,Test2,Test3") realtime logging is working. If I run thr same tests using orderedtest file) realtime logging isn't working. [Settings screenshot of both situations](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1324502.png). Why?

P.S. I have done recomendations by next link: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Visual+Studio+Tests#VisualStudioTests-Customtestlogger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, it's a bug. If anyone interesting, vote and follow by him here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-50684